# restkit text/plain error when postObject - response and request descriptors are setup correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest, restkit

I have a request descriptor setup for my rkobjectmanager and I have a proper response descriptor setup as well.

When I make a postObject call I immediately get a failure on the postObject call with:

```
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0x7faf525f8010 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:5000/date/cancel, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7faf524a9860> { URL: http://localhost:5000/date/cancel }, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7faf524dd970> { URL: http://localhost:5000/date/cancel } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 23 Jan 2015 18:46:40 GMT";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain}
2015-01-23 10:46:40.650 Whim[76057:1911786] D restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:210 response.body=
```

I have checked the manager right before this call and have verified that the request and response descriptors are properly formated.  I have several other response and request descriptors on this object manager and they work fine.

And Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked what is sent and server logs? In what cases does the server return plain text?

Comment: the server doesnt even get the request.

Comment: it seeems to fail immediatly on RestKit trying to send.

Comment: the JSON that is sent as a payload looks correct. (aka po operation.HTTPRequest.request.HTTPBody)

Comment: if I eliminate the object in the postObject command it also fails with the same error.

Comment: The error you see shows that the server did receive the request and respond (or perhaps did the first time and set cache headers so it isn't hit again...)

Answer (score 0):

RestKit usually expects a JSON object as a response. When I had this problem, there was a bug on the server side, and the server wasn't sending an object back. It was sending *nothing*, which is interpreted as text/plain. I had to fix the server method.